# Passing nested array to controller using ajax in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: arrays, asp.net-mvc-4, multidimensional-array, asp.net-ajax

Experts! I need your help! I wanted to pass a nested array to my controller, but my controller receive as a string with comma separated. How do I receive the nested array in my controller?

In Ajax Call:

```
var arr = new Array();

var setting1 = new Array();
setting1[0] = "example";
setting1[1] = "example";
setting1[2] = "example";
arr.push(setting1);

var setting2 = new Array();
setting2[0] = "example";
setting2[1] = "example";
setting2[2] = "example";
arr.push(setting2);

var setting3 = new Array();
setting3[0] = "example";
setting3[1] = "example";
setting3[2] = "example";
arr.push(setting2);

var url = "@Url.Action("action", "controller")";
$.ajax({
    traditional: true,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { arr: arr },
    url: url,
    success: function(data){alert("Success");},
    error: function(data){alert("Failed");}
});
```

In controller:

```
public JsonResult action(Array arr)
{
    //code goes here
}
```

I'm getting error saying that "[HTTP/1.1 414 Request-URI Too Long 4ms]"...For your information, the values stored in each setting element could be hundreds of length.